# How to prevent AngularJS 1.5 from escaping my URL hash and replacing '/' with '%2F'?

Tags: angularjs, url, escaping

We use angular 1.5, and have our own routing mechanism (by listening to `$locationChangeSuccess` event).

It works fine, but when I edit that hash part of the URL, and set it to `#a/b`, it is immediately replaced with `#a%2fb` (although  `$locaction.hash()` returns 'a\b').

**Any idea why this happens, and more importantly, how it can be prevented?**

At first I thought it is done be the browser, but when I add `#a/b` to the URL of a simple html file in the browser, the `/` remains, so I assume angular is involved here.

In my `app.ts`, `$locationProvider` is configured like this:

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at angular source and realized this is probably cannot be done with html enabled - hash part will always be encoded. But I did find out that the encoding used in the $location service is a custom encoding, and ':' is not encoded, so I switched from using '/' as a separator in the hash part to use ':'.

Answer (score 1):

Adding exclamation point **'!'** to your links should also do the job, for your case should be something like this:

```
<a href="#!a/b"
```